# Mongoose sort elements by counting numbers

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a documents like

```js
{
  data: [{"channel":"712064846325219432","message":1019},{"channel":"712064884812021801","message":4}],
  user: '290494169783205888',
},
{
  data: [{"channel":"712064846325219432","message":2000},{"channel":"712064884812021801","message":500}],
  user: '534099893979971584',
}
```

So how can I count `data`'s message and sort this documents by descending message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation pipeline stages [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) to count the message for each user then sort by the total number of messages. [Check the example.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OReTeqNoCSb)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$data"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$user",
      total_message: {
        $sum: "$data.message"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      total_message: -1
    }
  }
])
```

Results:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "534099893979971584",
    "total_message": 2500
  },
  {
    "_id": "290494169783205888",
    "total_message": 1023
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`Query.sort()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort)

For descending order you can either use `-1`, `desc` or `descending`

```js
Query.sort(message: -1)
```

Comment: thank you. but I think you misunderstood me. I edited my question.